# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/scan"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Getting an error for a simple index route in rails:

Here are my routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
scan_index GET  /scan/index(.:format) scan#index
      root GET  /                     scan#index
      scan GET  /scan(.:format)       scan#index
```

Yet, typing in the following url:

```
http://notrealurl.com/scan
```

Produces the following in error_log:

```
I, [2015-08-04T15:38:42.902191 #24943]  INFO -- : Started GET "/scan" at 2015-08-04 15:38:42 +0000
F, [2015-08-04T15:38:42.902936 #24943] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/scan"):
```

Comment: Can you post the `routes.rb` code in the question?

Comment: And also try  `scan_index` instead of `scan`

Comment: The problem was that the rails server needed to be restarted and I answered it, but for some reason my answer was deleted.